# Cloning HDD to SSD: will dd do the job?

Tags: windows, dd

I have a Windows7 problem, but since my guess is that there's a linux solution i'm posting here...

She Who Must Be Obeyed has an old Win7 box with a small HDD.  I want to migrate everything onto a (considerably bigger) SSD, which would replace the old drive.

However, the supplied software (Acronis) refuses to 'see' the SSD when connected through a USB dock; same for a couple of other Windoze applications.

My guess is that this is because the sector sizes are different on the two drives.   If i boot the box into linux with a live CD, would just dd-ing the HDD to the SSD leave me with a working (Win-bootable) SSD?  Or is the sector issue likely to stuff this as well?

Comment: For this exact operation, I've often used Partition Wizard with satisfaction.

Comment: Just tried it, refuses to copy across different sector sizes...?

Comment: You should take this opportunity to instead properly backup all personal files (better twice than once), do a clean new install of Windows 7 (if that is your wish) on the new SSD, and then copy over the personal files as well as reinstalling any needed applications. This would run far better, windows would see the SSD and (hopefully) do the relevant optimizations, etc... You will have far better success I believe than doing a low level copy, as Windows can be picky when hardware changes, etc...

Answer (score 2):

I would dump the Win7 image to an actual image using clonezilla or similar - this way you are only copying real data, not empty space on the drive.

Then restore the image to the new disk.

Answer (score 0):

Should work, just try it out:

```
dd if=/dev/HDD of=/dev/SSD
```